# FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/assign-symbols/-/assign-symbols-1.0.0.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, installation

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-qa>npm install
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/assign-symbols/-/assign-symbols-1.0.0.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at onerror (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agent-base\index.js:101:9)
npm ERR!     at callbackError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agent-base\index.js:123:5)
npm ERR!     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/assign-symbols/-/assign-symbols-1.0.0.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at onerror (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agent-base\index.js:101:9)
npm ERR!     at callbackError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agent-base\index.js:123:5)
npm ERR!     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\progr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-20T20_47_20_667Z-debug.log
```

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes that was the problem. and it is solved now. Thank you